# Вопрос программистам-схемотехникам. Что такое адрес команды в памяти? На физическом уровне

Tags: адрес

Процессор может обрабатывать команды напрямую, а может получать адрес команды, которая хранится в памяти, и потом производить обработку.

Адрес команды - это число. Но что за ним скрывается?

Я нигде не могу найти конкретное пояснение что именно скрывается за понятием "адрес команды или адрес данных в памяти". Всюду объяснение заканчивается на том, что это число и всё. За числом ведь скрываются определенным образом сконфигурированные транзисторы, какая-то логика

Какая связь между командой и её адресом в памяти? Предположим, что под командой понимается операция "ИЛИ", то есть определенным образом подключенные транзисторы. Тогда что такое адрес этой ячейки? Это уровни напряжения питания транзисторов в ней?

Объясните, пожалуйста, доступным примером

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то очень похоже что вы ищете описание как работает оператор CALL в assembler, суть в том, что сами инструкции хранятся в памяти, по адресу можно начать выполнение некоторой процедуры (набора инструкций), а затем вернуться в точку вызова (с помощью адреса возврата)

Comment: Адрес команды это содержимое регистра PC (или IC -- instruction counter). Далее, команда выбирается из памяти точно так же, как и любые другие данные, за исключением того, что данные попадают в кэш данных, а команды в кэш команд.

Comment: Для операции ИЛИ транзисторы разведены в процессоре, между его регистрами, а не в памяти. Перед тем как быть выполненной команда должна попасть в процессор. Поэтому процессор предварительно запрашивает у памяти дать ему очередную команду (на самом деле он работает блоками, а не по одной) и при этом он выдает в адресные линии памяти тот самый адрес (ну может не тот же самый и даже может не сам процессор, смотря как в данном железе выполнен MMU). точно так же он подгружает к себе данные для команды и вот когда уже все в нем, он наконец выполняет команду а результат кладет в память (если надо)

Comment: В современных ОС используется виртуальная память, так что до уровня физического адреса там ещё несколько шагов трансляции